# Error: Check the render method with react-redux connect()

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to learn redux with react-native, so I did some examples, but for everyone, even though they are different, I'm getting the same error.

[image]

My code is like this:

**index.js**:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/app';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('reduxExample', () => App);
```

**src/app.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import { Store } from './store';
import Home from './components/home';

export default props => (
  <Provider store={Store}>
    <Home />
  </Provider>
)
```

**src/components/home.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { View, Text, Button, Input } from 'react-native';

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    const { newValue } = this.props;

    return (
      <View>
        <Input type='text' />
        <Button>
          Click me!
        </Button>
        <Text>{newValue}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = store => ({
  newValue: store.clickState.newValue
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home)
```

**src/store/index.js**:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Reducers } from '../reducers';

export const Store = createStore(Reducers);
```

The rest I believe they do not have to deal with the problem but if I need to put the code.

Comment: Can you please also include your `./store.js`? Also, did you intend to specify that your `Home` component was on the path `./src/components/home.js`?

Comment: @CharlesSalmon I put the code that u ask for, and yes is src/comp...

Comment: wait there is no <Input /> in react native its <TextInput />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `<Input type='text' />` tag in react native. There is only a [`<TextInput />`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html) tag.